# Шрифт в процентах

Tags: html, css

Привет. Зачем в `body{font-size:62.5%}`? Во всех проектах нужно так записывать? Почему не задать жестко `10px.`? IE7 не может масштабировать шрифты в рх, поэтому так записали? Если умрет ие7, то этот способ умирает сам собой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, чтобы текст читался на дисплее с высоким ppi. Нет, пользователь может и нажать злосчастную комбинацию смены масштаба, но разве оно ему надо?

У браузеров есть проблемы с различением пикселей CSS и экранных пикселей. Про это много написано, [например в статье «A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel»](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html). Про CSSные пиксели, [говорят](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Using_Pixels), нормально знает только Opera под OS X — остальные браузеры радостно игнорируют ppi дисплея.

Answer (score 1):

Кто сказал что нельзя? Да хоть в px, хоть в %, хоть в em.

Comment: Плюсану потому что Баааа знакомые всё литса

Comment: @karmadro4, мы знакомы, да? :-)))